# How to list tweet texts using nodejs and mongodb from streaming api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter

I am trying to use nodejs and mongodb. I can enter tweets to a collection with using a  function  of `ntwitter`

```
twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'track':'dio'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
    var tweet = data.text;   
    tweetCollection.insert(tweet,function(error){
            if(error)  {
                console.log("Error", error.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Inserted into database");
            }
    });
  });
});
```

When I try to get the tweets from the collection I use express , nodejs and mongo and use them as below :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var content = fs.readFileSync("template.html");

    getTweets(function(tweets){

        console.log(tweets);
        var  ul = '';
        tweets.forEach(function(tweet){
            ul +='<li><strong>'  + ":</strong>" + tweet["text"] + "</li>";
        });
        content = content.toString("utf8").replace("{{INITIAL_TWEETS}}", ul);
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        res.send(content);
        });

});
db.open(function(error) {
    console.log("We are connected " + host + ":"+ port);

    db.collection("tweet",function(error, collection){
            tweetCollection = collection;            
    });
});
function getTweets(callback) {
    tweetCollection.find({}, { "limit":10, "sort":{"_id":-1} } , function(error, cursor){
            cursor.toArray(function(error, tweets){

                callback(tweets);
            });
    });
};
```

In the console.log I see tweets as in this [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/AqG8VWJz)

In the browser I get an unordered list of

```
:undefined
:undefined
```

What can I do to show tweets text ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not storing the entire tweet object, just the text. So the mongodb driver sees your string as an array, hence the array-like object properties you're seeing.

Try this line:

```
tweetCollection.insert(data,function(error){
```

instead of:

```
tweetCollection.insert(tweet,function(error){
```

Or if you really just want to store the text, try something like:

```
tweetCollection.insert({ text: tweet },function(error){
```